# Update Google map by latitude and longitude form

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

So I am building a HTML page, in which i need a Google Map and a simple form which consists of two fields latitude and longitude.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map-canvas { height: 100% }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyA_0qaGwK5ZWdKYXHRlJ-05CI_geHWo6v4&sensor=false">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
          zoom: 8,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
            mapOptions);
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

So this is the code to embed a map, from what i have to figured that I need to create a form  which change the values of this line :

```
center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)
```

and updates it whenever I press the update button or submit button. I know how to create a form but don't know how exactly to use in the above code.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Simple Map</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
  html, body, #map-canvas {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
  }
</style>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
  <script>
    var map;
    function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 8,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
  mapOptions);
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    function pan() {
        var panPoint = new google.maps.LatLng(document.getElementById("lat").value, document.getElementById("lng").value);
        map.panTo(panPoint)
     }
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <label>lat</label><input type="text" id="lat" />
<br/>
  <label>lng</label><input type="text" id="lng" />
 <input type="button" value="updateCenter" onclick="pan()" />


 <div id="map-canvas"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use api documentation of google maps

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map

In your condition you should use set map method:

```
<input type="button" onclick="map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644))" value="test"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an elegant solution, moves the camera to the point.

```
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
map.panTo(myLatlng);
```

This jumps directly to the point.

```
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
map.setCenter(myLatlng);
```

Comment: how do i use this with a form mate .?

Comment: This is something i wrote that might come in handy, or help you to come up with your solution http://pastie.org/7742029

Comment: I really don't understand that all I need is a form of two fields latitude and longitude , clicking submit takes me to the place

Comment: Okay, you can simply do that by using the code i sent you, then you have to do is initialize the map, and then <button onclick="mapObject.center($('#lon').val(),$('#lat').val()); void(0);">Center</button><input type="text" id="lon" /><input type="text" id="lat" />

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who will come later, suppose you want to update your map latitudes and longitudes from an array(like in case you have a list of cities), you can try this:

> Globaly declare your variables and array

```
var latlon;
var map;
var coords = {
'agra': '27.1767, 78.0081',
'noida': '28.5355, 77.3910',
'kanpur':'26.4499, 80.3319',
};
```

> Add a function that will work on your selects on change, so that when you change a city, the map automatically changes.

```
function firemapChange(value)
{
var c = coords[value].split(',');
var latlon = new google.maps.LatLng(c[0], c[1]);
// map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapdiv'), {
//center: {lat: position.coords.latitude, lng: position.coords.longitude},
// center: latlon,
//  zoom: 13,
//  mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
map.panTo(latlon);
}
```

> Why i have commented so many lines?
>   It is because i was accidentally creating a new map object. Since my map also had a search box, the search box disappeared and all its functionality was lost. So, it is better to avoid creating a new map, and create a global variable
>
> finally in your HTML, you do something like this:

```
<label style="font-size:11px;">City
</label>
</td>
<td>
  <select size="auto" style="font-size:11px;" onChange="firemapChange(this.value)">
    <option value="select city" id="b1">Select City
    </option>
    <option value="noida" id="b1">Noida
    </option>
    <option value="agra" id="b1">Agra
    </option>
    <option value="kanpur" id="b1">Kanpur
    </option>
    </td> 
</tr>
```