# Update lat and lng values with google maps api before submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a custom form with google autocomplete in my input. Once i select a location and click submit, the values of latitude and longitude update with the position values to do the search.

I can't find a way to stop the form from submit until the values are updated, i tried different events like onchange or keyup, but this do many calls to the api and is not a good answer to this.

```
function geocodeAddress(geocoder) {
  var address = document.getElementById('autoc-input-maps').value;
  geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK){
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: results[0].geometry.location
      });
      jQuery("#lat").val(marker.position.lat());
      jQuery("#lng").val(marker.position.lng());

    } else {
      console.log('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
  });
}

  function updatecords() { 
      var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
      geocodeAddress(geocoder); 
  }

jQuery('#auto-search').submit(function() {
  updatecords();
  return true;
});
```

I tried to set a timeout on the submit too and didnt work.

Comment: You need to submit the form in the geocoder callback function when the coordinates are available.

Answer (score 0):

Another question similar to this was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296320/update-google-map-by-latitude-and-longitude-form). I think you could use this function:

```
function pan() {
        var panPoint = new google.maps.LatLng(document.getElementById("lat").value, document.getElementById("lng").value);
        map.panTo(panPoint)
     }
```

Hope this helps!